# how to get tooltip text from canvas using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, canvas, webdriver, tooltip

It will be a great help if someone help me out with below problem.

Here I am trying to get `tooltip` text associated with mouse hover on the first gray box in the first row. But still no luck. Please let me know in case of additional details.

Web Link :-https://www.redbus.in/search?fromCityName=Bangalore&fromCityId=122&toCityName=Goa&toCityId=210&onward=25-Aug-2017&opId=0&busType=Any#

```
public class RedBus {

    WebDriver driver;
    WebDriverWait wait;

    @BeforeTest
    public void run() {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\geckodriver.exe");
        String baseUrl="https://www.redbus.in/";
        driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,5);
    }

    @Test
    public void testFunctionality() {

        try { 
            driver.findElement(By.id("src")).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.id("src")).sendKeys("Bangalore");
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("li.selected")));
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li.selected")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.id("dest")).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.id("dest")).sendKeys("Goa");
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("li.selected")));
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li.selected")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='rb-calendar_onward_cal']/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[3]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.id("search_btn")).click();

            String Busname=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul//li[2]//div[@class='service-name']")).getText();
            String departTime=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul//li[2]//div[@class='fl depart']")).getText();
            String arrivalTime=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul//li[2]//div[@class='fl arrive']")).getText();
            String totalSeats=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul//li[2]//div[@class='fl seats']//span[@class='tot-seats']")).getText();
            String fare=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul//li[2]//div[@class='fare']")).getText();

           System.out.println(Busname+" "+departTime+" "+arrivalTime+" "+totalSeats+" "+fare );

           driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul//li[2]//button[@class='view-seats button to-be-hidden']")).click();

           Actions builder=new Actions(driver);

           wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='upper-canvas canvas-wrapper']//canvas")));

           WebElement Upper=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='upper-canvas canvas-wrapper']//canvas"));

           Action movetoUpper=builder.moveToElement(Upper).build(); 

           movetoUpper.perform();

           System.out.println("tooltip text"+  Upper.getAttribute("title"));
           System.out.println("SEAT NO:"+  Upper.getText());

        }
        catch(NoSuchElementException ex) {
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: you are not mouse hovering to a particular seat. The xpath selects all the seats. I feel getAttribute("title") actually works if we hover to a particular seat. Correct me if i miss something. Thanks.

Comment: Yes you are right but I am unable to get XPath for a single seat. The canvas containing all seats is getting selected as a whole.

Comment: @santhoshkumar yes that's right but when you will try to find XPath of a particular seat using inspect element the canvas tag containing all seats will get selected as a whole.. That's the main problem here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes you are correct. We are not able to identify individual seats. There is no straight way to achieve this.

Comment: @santhoshkumar Please help me with any way possible to capture this tooltip text in this case.

Comment: You can try using x and y coordinates of a particular seat to hover.

Comment: @santhoshkumar                                                                                 
Tried adding below code. Still unable to get location of individual seat.                                                                           /*        Point point=Upper.getLocation();
  Action movetoUpper=builder.moveToElement(Upper,point.getX(),point.getY()).build();     movetoUpper.perform(); /* getting below exception        
org.openqa.selenium.interactions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: (734.1499938964844, 1495.7999877929688) is out of bounds of viewport width (1366) and height (669)